# get-line gets always the same line C++

Tags: c++, file, c++11, getline

I have a file with data like this

```
10000 9.425 1.00216 -0.149976
20000 19.425 0.973893 -0.135456
30000 29.425 1.01707 -0.115423
40000 39.425 1.0181 -0.12074
.
.
.
```

to get the data what I am doing is to read the whole line and then separate the line by the spaces to get the data I need. The problem is that the file has 3000 lines so I tried to get the line in a for loop

```
  std::vector<std::string> a;
  std::ifstream datas("Data/thermo_stability.dat");
  std::string str;
  char d=' ';
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
      std::getline(datas, str);
      tokenize(str,d,a);
      x[i]=std::atof((a[1]).c_str());
      y[i]=std::atof((a[3]).c_str());
      std::cout << x[i] << "\t" << y[i] << std::endl;
    }
```

I noticed that something was wrong so I added that cout and found out that it was always getting the same line. How can I fix this problem? Why is not getting the next line after getline is called? When I do it outside the loop it goes to the next line.

EDIT

here is the tokenized function

```
void tokenize(std::string &str, char delim, std::vector<std::string> &out)
{
  size_t start;
  size_t end = 0;
  
  while ((start = str.find_first_not_of(delim, end)) != std::string::npos)
    {
      end = str.find(delim, start);
      out.push_back(str.substr(start, end - start));
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know its not getting the next line. You don't print out `str`. Looks more like that `tokenize()` is failing to read the string into `a` But we can't tell because you don't show that function.

Comment: Please [edit] this question to include a [mre].  This code could either work or fail, depending on the parts that are not shown here.

Comment: I added the tokenize function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have some issues with that code:

I don't see where `n` is set so how do you know it is correct. The proper way to read a line is to call `getline()` and then test it worked (it can be done in a single line).

```
 while(std::getline(datas, str)) {
     // Successfully read a line from the file
 }
```

You don't need to manually convert string to integers or floats. The stream library will do that automatically.

```
    std::istringstream lineStream(std::move(str));
    str.clear();

    int value1;     // please use better names:
    double value2;
    double value3;
    double value4;

    lineStream >> value1 >> value2 >> value3 >> value4;
```

Comment: I tried the std::stringstream lineStream and the compiler says that std::stringstream lineStream’ has initializer but incomplete type. Also, doesn't know what line.clear and std::move is. Do I have to include some other library to use it?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream   https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move  line.clear() was a typo fixed.

Comment: Prefer to use [`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream/basic_istringstream) instead when parsing input. And there is no need to `clear()` a newly constructed stream object.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I am clearing the original string. After the move it is in valid but undefined state. Just making sure it is empty (in a valid and known state).

Comment: @MartinYork you `move`'d the string, so there is nothing left to clear.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Its not the clearing I am after. I just like to know the state of my variables. clear() does not have a precondition and by calling clear we put it in a well-defined state. Yes its probably not dong anything.